# What is g_type_init() and how to call?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, wxwidgets

I'm coding a little game using C++ and wxWidgets:

- IDE: Eclipse
- Ubuntu 12.04 using Unity
- wxWidgets 2.8
- glib2.0-2.34.1

I get the following runtime error:

```
(process:14421): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.34.1/./gobject /gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:14421): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed

(process:14421): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion `GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(process:14421): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.34.1/./gobject/gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:14421): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed

(process:14421): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.34.1/./gobject/gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:14421): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.34.1/./gobject/gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:14421): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.34.1/./gobject/gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:14421): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed
```

I did some research, but I do not realy understand:

- What does g_type_init() do?

And more important:

- What headerfiles and libraries do I have to include, or what is maybe missing on my system?

**Edit**
*Additional code:*

```
#include "../GUI/gui.h"

int main()
{

wxWindow myParent;

Spielfenster meinFenster(&myParent);

return 0;
}
```

GUI header-file:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// C++ code generated with wxFormBuilder (version Dec 21 2009)
// http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
//
// PLEASE DO "NOT" EDIT THIS FILE!
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef __gui__
#define __gui__

#include <wx/string.h>
#include <wx/stattext.h>
#include <wx/gdicmn.h>
#include <wx/font.h>
#include <wx/colour.h>
#include <wx/settings.h>
#include <wx/sizer.h>
#include <wx/frame.h>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Class Spielfenster
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Spielfenster : public wxFrame 
{
private:

protected:
    wxStaticText* m_staticText6;
    wxStaticText* m_staticText7;
    wxStaticText* m_staticText8;
    wxStaticText* m_staticText9;
    wxStaticText* m_staticText10;

public:

    Spielfenster( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, const wxString& title = wxT("Feuerwerk"), const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxSize( 600,400 ), long style = wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
    ~Spielfenster();

};

#endif //__gui__
```

GUI cpp-file:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// C++ code generated with wxFormBuilder (version Dec 21 2009)
// http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
//
// PLEASE DO "NOT" EDIT THIS FILE!
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "gui.h"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Spielfenster::Spielfenster( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, long style ) : wxFrame( parent, id, title, pos, size, style )
{
this->SetSizeHints( wxDefaultSize, wxDefaultSize );

wxBoxSizer* bSizer2;
bSizer2 = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

wxGridSizer* gSizer3;
gSizer3 = new wxGridSizer( 1, 5, 0, 0 );

m_staticText6 = new wxStaticText( this, wxID_ANY, wxT("HandCard1"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
m_staticText6->Wrap( -1 );
gSizer3->Add( m_staticText6, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxEXPAND, 5 );

m_staticText7 = new wxStaticText( this, wxID_ANY, wxT("HandCard2"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
m_staticText7->Wrap( -1 );
gSizer3->Add( m_staticText7, 0, wxEXPAND, 5 );

m_staticText8 = new wxStaticText( this, wxID_ANY, wxT("HandCard3"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
m_staticText8->Wrap( -1 );
gSizer3->Add( m_staticText8, 0, wxEXPAND, 5 );

m_staticText9 = new wxStaticText( this, wxID_ANY, wxT("HandCard4"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
m_staticText9->Wrap( -1 );
gSizer3->Add( m_staticText9, 0, wxEXPAND, 5 );

m_staticText10 = new wxStaticText( this, wxID_ANY, wxT("HandCard5"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
m_staticText10->Wrap( -1 );
gSizer3->Add( m_staticText10, 0, wxEXPAND, 5 );

bSizer2->Add( gSizer3, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );

this->SetSizer( bSizer2 );
this->Layout();
}

Spielfenster::~Spielfenster()
```

Compiler Call:

```
g++ -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/gtk -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0  -std=gnu++11 -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"gui.d" -MT"gui.d" -o "gui.o" "/home/michael/workspace/GUI/gui.cpp"
```

Linker call:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread -L/usr/lib/wxformbuilder -o "Fireworks"  ./card.o ./game.o ./gui.o ./hello.o ./set.o ./stack.o   -lwx_gtk2u_richtext-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_aui-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_html-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_core-2.8 -lwx_baseu_xml-2.8 -lwx_baseu_net-2.8 -lwx_baseu-2.8
```

Something strange I observed is, that Eclipse still gives me errors in gui.h and gui.cpp like "Type 'wxStaticText' could not be resolved" but compiles... Could this be a hint?

**Edit2**
If I do it the "helloworld way" from this site it works: http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hworld.txt
Then I get no error with g_type_init() as a suggestion. Do not know (yet) what the real difference is.

Comment: 404, edit2 is no longer available. Please update.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem of missing headers or libraries but of a bug somewhere. If you are not using GTK+/Glib directly, it must be a wxWidgets bug, but I have no idea how could this happen, so some more information would be needed to understand what's going on: either a small, simple example reproducing the problem or at least the backtrace from gdb when the error message is given (to obtain it, run your program under gdb and put a breakpoint on `g_log`, then do `bt` when it is hit).

Comment: BTW: Thanks a lot for your hints. My question above was more about g_type_init() and what I have to include to make it working. But sure, maybe it should not be necessary to execute g_type_init() and ther is a deeper bug somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Came across this problem and this stackoverflow post - not when using wxWidgets, but when creating a custom composite GTK widget and instantiating it in a test program.

Looking at the source for gtype.c

```
 124 #define g_return_val_if_type_system_uninitialized(return_value) G_STMT_START{ \
 125     if (G_UNLIKELY (!static_quark_type_flags))                                \
 126       {                                                                       \
 127         g_log (G_LOG_DOMAIN, G_LOG_LEVEL_CRITICAL,                            \
 128                "%s: You forgot to call g_type_init()",                        \
 129                G_STRLOC);                                                     \
 130         return (return_value);                                                \
 131       }                                                                       \
 132 }G_STMT_END
```

It says something like this when the type system is uninitialized.

In my case, I was creating a new custom widget before gtk_init was called in main.

Moving the creation of the custom widget to **after** the call to `gtk_init(&argc, &argv)` fixed the problem.